# Integral closure of $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification

I want to check my proof that the integral closure of $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$ is itself, assuming $k$ is characteristic 0 (if anyone knows how to deal with the case when $k$ has characteristic 2 feel free to also say).

Proof: $k[x,y]$ is integrally closed and so the integral closure of $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$ is contained in $k[x,y].$ But also the integral elements over $k[x^2,xy,y^2]$ are fixed by the involution of $k[x,y]$ sending $x,y$ to $-x,-y$, meaning that they belong to $k[x^2,xy,y^2],$ proving the ring is integrally closed.

Comment: Isn't $x$ an integral element over $k[x^2,xy, y^2]=R$? It seems to be a root of $X^2 - x^2\in R[X]$ .

Comment: @rschwieb $x$ does not belong to the field of fractions though.

Comment: Ah i see :) I didn't account for it only applying to the fractions using $R$ alone

Comment: For any field $k$, $k[x^2,xy,y^2]\cong k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)=R$, and $R=R_x\cap R_y$ is the intersection of two  normal domain, therefore normal.